# Dialekte mit Vorname + Artikel, wann kein Artikel erlaubt?

Tags: article, dialect, regional, person-names

Viele Dialekte benutzen Vornamen generell mit Artikeln (zumindest in der Alltagssprache), wie z.B.:

- Weißt du, wo *der Peter* ist?
- Ich treffe mich morgen mit *der Susi*.
- Ich gehe nachher *zum Frank*.
- Ich mag *die Anna* nicht.

Aber gibt es da auch Konstruktionen, wo der Artikel nicht erlaubt ist?

Konkrekt fiel mir das auf, wenn man jemanden namentlich vorstellt.

Das hier ist ok:

- Das ist *der Peter*.
- Das ist *die Susi*.

aber das scheint mir fragwürdig:

- * Er heißt *der Peter*.
- * Sie heißt *die Susi*.

Ist das bei euch im Dialekt erlaubt? Und wenn nicht, wie falsch klingt das? Wäre es zumindest tolerierbar, wenn auch unüblich?

Gibt es andere Situationen, wo man keinen Artikel benutzen kann?

Bei Anreden ist das sicher generell nicht erlaubt:

- * Hey, *der Peter*, komm mal her!
- * *Die Susi*, welches Buch liest du da?

Wo noch?

(Wie gesagt, ich bin nur an Dialekten interessiert, wo Artikel mit Vornamen generell üblich sind.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hochdeutsch geht auch das nicht:

> - Das, was du *Tüsch* nennst, heißt *der Tisch*.

Das würde bedeuten, dass der Artikel ein Teil des Namens ist. In dem Satz

> - Er heißt *der Peter*.

ist das ganz gleich.

Das liegt aber nicht, wie man auf den ersten Blick vermuten könnte, daran, dass hier der Gleichsetzungsnominativ verwendet wird. Denn in

> Das hier ist der Peter

wird ebenfalls ein Gleichsetzungsnominativ verwendet. Hier ist der Artikel aber in den Dialekten, um die es hier geht, sehr wohl gängig.

Kommen wir zur Anrede:

> - Hey, der Peter, komm mal her!

Dort, wo der Vokativ verwendet wird, ist der Artikel ebenfalls nicht angebracht, wobei im Hochdeutschen der Vokativ mit den Nominativ identisch ist (Anredenominativ). In jenen Dialekten, in denen Namen mit Artikel verwendet werden, unterscheiden sich Vokativ und Nominativ eben genau darin, dass der Vokativ ohne Artikel verwendet wird, während der Nominativ mit Artikel erscheint.

Comment: Wie sieht's mit "nennen" aus?

- Sie heißt Susanne, aber wir nennen sie *die Susi*.

Comment: @stef: Ich finde, es gilt dasselbe wie bei *heißen*. Das funktioniert nur dort, wo der Artikel tatsächlich wie ein Teil des Namens verwendet wird, z.B. bei Opernsängerinnen: »Man nennt sie *die Netrebko.*« »Die Netrebko« auf [nachrichten.at](http://www.nachrichten.at/nachrichten/kultur/Eine-Linzerin-dirigiert-die-Netrebko-ins-Salzburger-Scheinwerfer-Licht;art16,2648290), im [Salzburger Fenster](http://www.salzburger-fenster.at/2017/03/27/die-netrebko-zahlt-zurueck/) und beim [SWR](https://www.swr.de/swr2/musik/netrebko-im-sommerinterview/-/id=661124/did=20095606/nid=661124/36btl/index.html)

Comment: Sie heißt Dianna, aber wir nennen sie "die Anna", und er, Derrick, aber "den Rick".

Answer (score 2):

Ich glaube, das ist nicht wirklich an einen Dialekt gebunden. Umgangssprachlich ist es (meines Wissens) in Deutschland eher die Regel als die Ausnahme, "der Peter" und "die Susi" zu sagen. Nicht erlaubt ist es in formeller Sprache (z.B. eine Rede) und in der Schriftsprache (es sei denn, sie will bewusst Umgangssprache wiedergeben).

Ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, dass irgendwo "Er heißt der Peter" gesagt wird, das klingt völlig abwegig. Er heißt ja auch "Peter" und nicht "der Peter". Kann ich zumindest für hier (Frankfurt) komplett ausschließen.

Zur Unterscheidung würde ich sagen, dass "Das ist..." dazu dient, jemanden zu identifizieren, das kann sein Name sein, muss aber nicht ("Das ist der Chef" / "Das ist unsere Schnapsdrossel"). Das Wort "heißen" dagegen dient ausschließlich dazu, den Namen zu nennen, deswegen fällt hier wahrscheinlich der Artikel weg.

Die Anrede ist ein anderer Sonderfall, da wird ja grundsätzlich kein Artikel verwendet ("Der Herr Doktor" ist in einem Aussage- oder Fragesatz erlaubt, aber nicht in der Anrede).

Ein Fall, der mir jetzt noch einfällt, bei dem auch umgangssprachlich kein Artikel gebraucht wird, ist der Genitiv ("Peters Haus"). "Des Peters Haus" gibt es meines Wissens nicht. Umgangssprachlich gibt es natürlich auch "Dem Peter sein Haus" oder "Peter sein Haus" (was dann eigentlich kein Genitiv mehr ist), aber nach meiner Erfahrung werden diese Formen gemischt benutzt, d.h. viele Sprecher, die im Nominativ und Akkusativ *immer* den Artikel benutzen, sagen trotzdem oft "Peters Haus".

Answer (score 2):

Ich denke, die Frage muß man "vom Schwanz her aufzäumen" - Nachdem Artikel generell kein genuin notwendiges Konzept sind und Sprachen wie Latein oder viele slawische Sprachen z.B. ganz gut ohne auskommen, gab es sicher in der historischen Sprachentwicklung einen Grund, warum fast alle Indogermanische Sprachen trotzdem welche haben. Die Frage ist nun: "Warum war dieser Grund speziell für Namen in der Hochsprache anscheinend nicht gut genug, in Dialekten aber schon?"

Gute Gründe für die Entwicklung von Artikeln könnten folgende gewesen sein:

1. Die Möglichkeit, *definit* von *indefinit* zu unterscheiden. Meint man irgendein, oder ein spezifisches Ding.
2. Da Artikel flektiert werden, transportieren sie eine *Vorbereitung* auf den Fall des Substantives, das ihnen folgt, also eigentlich redundante Information, die aber dem Hörenden das Verstehen einfacher macht. (Dieser Punkt ist m. A. nach ein sehr wichtiger, gilt aber nur für die deutsche Sprache, das Englische z.B. flektiert keine Artikel)

(1) Scheint kein guter Grund für die Anwendung von Artikeln bei Namen zu sein - Namen sind per se in den meisten Fällen definit - In den wenigen Ausnahmen, wo sie's nicht sind, ist eine Umschreibung wie "irgendso'n Peter" oder "some John" sicher angebrachter.

(2) Ist ein sehr guter Grund, an sich ist die *Vorankündigung* von Kasus und Numerus bei Namen genauso nützlich für die Verständlichkeit wie bei "normalen Substantiven". Da Namen außer im Genitiv normalerweise nicht flektiert werden, wären Artikel eigentlich umso nützlicher. An sich muß man sich fragen, warum die Hochsprache hier die Artikel nicht für nützlich genug "gehalten hat", um sie anzuwenden - Das wäre aber eine andere Frage.

Nun haben Dialekte normalerweise ein schwächeres Kasussystem wie die Hochsprache (viele kennen keinen z.B. Genitiv, usw.), was darauf schließen läßt, dass sich die "einfachere Sprache" nicht mit sowas kompliziertem wie Fällen herumschlagen will. Ein bißchen Hilfe von Artikeln war hier sicher willkommen. Ich glaube, Dialekte gehen ein bißchen pragmatischer mit der Sprache um und verwenden einfach, was nützlich ist.

Ein weiterer Widerspruch bei der Nicht-Verwendung von Artikeln bei Eigennamen ist auch, dass der Null-Artikel bei "normalen" Substantiven an sich schon mit einer anderen Bedeutung belegt ist, die z.B. Unzählbarkeit "Ich kaufe Bücher" oder Generizität "Herr Schmitz ist Arzt" transportiert (Was bei Namen irgendwie unpassend erscheint).

Man stelle sich einfache Konstrukte vor, die in Dialekten durchaus üblich sind, wie

> Die ist dem Peter [seine Frau, seine Tochter]

Solche Konstrukte sind ohne Artikel extrem schwer vorstellbar bzw. wären fast unverständlich.

Im "deutschen Vokativ" (den es nicht wirklich gibt) würde ein Artikel nichts Hilfreiches beitragen. Im Allgemeinen weiß der Hörer hier wohl schon, dass er gemeint ist - Warum sollte man einen Artikel hinzufügen.

Bei der Vorstellung dient der Artikel in "Das ist der Peter" als Verstärkung des Demonstrativpronomens, bei "ich treffe mich mit der Susi" zum Transportieren der Definiteigenschaft (genau die Susi).

Zusammengefasst: Artikel vereinfachen die Verständlichkeit, indem sie den Hörer auf das, was kommt, vorbereiten . Es gibt wenig gute Gründe, ausgerechnet bei Namen, die eben nicht flektiert werden, darauf zu verzichten. Dialekte sind hier wahrscheinlich einfach ein bißchen pragmatischer als die Hochsprache.